# No response from FCM

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a raspberryPI with Apache and PHP5 installed. I found this code for FCM notifications:

```
<?php
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'MYAPIACCESSKEY' );

$messaggio = "Prova 1";
  $registrationIds="MYDEVICEID";

$body="There's something new!";
$title = "Touch here to open";
$registrationIds = (array)$registrationIds;


$msg = array
(
     "body" => $body,
     "title" => $title,
     "sound" => "default"
);

$data = array
(

     "Messaggio" => $messaggio,

);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'notification' => $msg,
    'data' => $data
);



$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key='.API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;

?>
```

The problem is that from my local network ( with dynamic IP address) the message is sent and received, while from another location (with static IP address) I get literaly no response (but with 200 status code) from FCM. There's maybe some IP configuration to do with the Firebase Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the IP to the allowed IP that can send request to your firebase push application service. console.cloud.google.com

[image: You have to add the IP to the allowed IP that can send request to your firebase push application service. console.cloud.google.com]